# ＜送信＞ボタンで、入力フォームのデータをサーバー（または、メール）に送信したいがエラーになる

Tags: monaca, html5

よくある画面で、入力フォームで入力したデータを＜送信＞ボタンにより送信したいのですが、実機でデバックすると、「ネットワークエラーが発生しました。（file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/file/projects/cloud/・・・/www/mail.php）」というエラーメッセージが出ます。何か設定したりするところは、ありますか？無料版ではできませんか？
（以下コード）

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ja">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
<p><label>名前：<input type="text" name="name" size="40"></label></p>
<p><label>コメント：<br><textarea name="comments" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea></label></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="送信"><input type="reset" value="リセット"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

action 属性が相対URLで指定されているため、デバッガ上の `mail.php` に送信しようとしています。

`mail.php` が置かれた場所にアップロードすれば動作すると思いますが、デバッガ上で動かしたいのであれば、 action 属性を `http://hogehoge.com/mail.php` のように絶対URLで指定する必要があります。

Comment: unaristさん、ありがとうございました。理解できました。ご指摘の所を変更したところ、今までのエラーはでなくなりましたが、monacaのプレビューで実行すると、「405 Not Allowed」のエラーがでます。また、実機でクラウド接続してみると、エラーはでませんが、画面上に数個の記号（「";?>」）がでます。データも受け渡されてないみたいですし、phpファイル内に書いたprintも効いていないようです。monacaサーバの設定とかあるのでしょうか？

Comment: Monaca を使わずに、 `mail.php` が動作することは確認されましたか？質問にあるHTMLであればこのままWebサーバーに置けば動作確認できると思います。

Comment: 念のため書いておきますが、Monaca単体でphpを動かすことはできません。phpの動くサーバーを別途用意し、そこにMonacaアプリからアクセスすることになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。PHPが出来ないということは、こういう事だったんですね。難しそうなので、研究してみます。